# Tkinter Syntax issue

Tags: python, tkinter, subprocess

I have been trying to work with Tkinter to create a GUI to choose programs/Website
to launch upon startup.

The Webbrowser and subprocess.exe opener worked correctly in other scripts, and the template for the Tkinter script worked but when I start adding more variables 
it states invalid syntax (specifically on the `CoWeb` variable, on the def)

Can anyone help me with this? Am I missing something basic?

```
from Tkinter import Tk, Label, Button
import subprocess
import webbrowser

class MyFirstGUI:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title("Greetings")

        self.label = Label(master, text="Good Morning Mr. Swordy. What would you like to do?")
        self.label.pack()

        self.CoWeb_button = Button(master, text="ENE Website", command=self.CoWeb)
        self.CoWeb_button.pack()

        self.ProjWeb_button = Button(master, text="ENE Projects", command=self.ProjWeb)
        self.ProjWeb_button.pack()

        self.Excel_button = Button(master, text="Excel", command=self.Excel)
        self.Excel_button.pack()

        self.AutoCAD_button = Button(master, text="AutoCAD", command=self.AutoCAD)
        self.AutoCAD_button.pack()

        self.GEarth_button = Button(master, text="Google Earth", command=self.GEarth)
        self.GEarth_button.pack()

        self.close_button = Button(master, text="Close", command=master.quit)
        self.close_button.pack()



def Excel(self):
        subprocess.Popen([r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office16\EXCEL.EXE"]

    def CoWeb(self):
        url = "https://intranet.enengineering.com/SitePages/Home.aspx"
        webbrowser.open_new(url)

    def ProjWeb(self):
        url = "https://eneprojects.enengineering.com/SitePages/Home.aspx"
        webbrowser.open_new(url)

    def AutoCAD(self):
        subprocess.Popen([r"C:\Program Files\Autodesk\AutoCAD 2016\acad.exe"]

    def GEarth(self):
        subprocess.Popen([r""C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Google Earth Pro\client\googleearth.exe"]


root = Tk()
my_gui = MyFirstGUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You forgot the closing bracket in all your `subprocess.Popen([..]`.

Comment: always put in question FULL error message (Traceback)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This no valid Python syntax:

```
def GEarth(self):
        subprocess.Popen([r""C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Google Earth Pro\client\googleearth.exe"]
```

Note the  double `"`, i.e. `""`.
Just remove one `"`:

```
def GEarth(self):
        subprocess.Popen([r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Google Earth Pro\client\googleearth.exe"]
```

Furthermore, your indentation seems wrong.

The definitions of:

```
def Excel(self):
...  
def CoWeb(self):
```

must be on the same level as:

```
def __init__(self, master):
```

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunatly it is still returning errors, It states:" Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/ArcGIS10.3/Scripts/TkinterGui", line 51, in <module>
    my_gui = MyFirstGUI(root)
  File "C:/Python27/ArcGIS10.3/Scripts/TkinterGui", line 30, in __init__
    self.CoWeb_button = Button(master, text="ENE Website", command=self.CoWeb)
AttributeError: MyFirstGUI instance has no attribute 'CoWeb'"

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing the closing paren on this statement:

```
def Excel(self):
    subprocess.Popen([r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office16\EXCEL.EXE"]
```

Closing paren is also missing in AutoCAD and GEarth methods.